# What are kubernetes or google kuberenetes engine "workloads"?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-workloads-overview

Im a little confused, the GCP kubernetes web console has a "workloads" section that seems to just have k8s "deployments". and In k8s documentations "workloads" is a section (empty): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/

Are "workloads" an actual thing? Is there a "workloads" class? Or is workloads just used in the general sense of the term in the gke console and k8s documentation?

edit: ===============

Is there specific documentation for what google considers a GKE "workload" and a list of what will appear under the "Workloads" section of the GKE web console in gcp? Will the GCP "Workloads" section include only the following components?
[image]

Comment: I get the impression that it's an overarching term for things they produce pods (or maybe inclusive of pods).

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/ is not a page. It's a just path. You should take a look into the pages those are under this path link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a general term for ways to run "compute-ish stuff" on Kubernetes. The page in the Kubernetes docs is blank because it's only there for the table of contents tree on the left side of the page. As shown there, there are several types of Kubernetes objects that are generally a "workload". The simplest is a bare Pod, which is usually just a single container running somewhere. From there you have things like Deployments (multiple copies of a container), StatefulSets (multiple copies but with some special properties), Jobs ("run once" style stuff), and many more.

Comment: Is there a specific google doc that classifies all "workload" items that will appear under the "workloads" section of the web console?

Comment: Here a Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/) about GKE concept and you will find a workload section

Answer (score 3):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads is not a page. It's a just path. You should take a look into the pages those are under this path link.

Kubernetes workloads means all of the followings that has a `podspec` and can run containers. It includes:

- Deployment
- StatefulSet
- ReplicaSet
- ReplicationController (will be depricate in future)
- DaemonSet
- Job
- CronJob
- Pod

Comment: So this is what will appear under the "workloads" section in GCP console?

Comment: also everything that has a podspec is the same as saying everything that is owned by a kublete correct?